# an infinitely differentiable monotonic function that goes to 0 at infinity but f' does not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

We want infinitely differentiable monotonic function f such that: $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) \neq 0$.

An infinitely differentiable bridging function, strictly monotonic on $[0,1]$ which will help us in our example:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 0 \\
                       \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}\exp(\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2})) & 0 < x < 1 \\
                       1 & x\geq1
                     \end{cases}$$
Let f(x) be equal 1 for $x\leq1$, equal $\frac{1}{n}$ on the closed interval $[2n-1,2n]$ for $n=1,2,...$ and on the intervening intervals $(2n,2n+1)$ define f(x) by translations of the bridging functions with appropriate negative factors for changes in the vertical scale.

My question is why $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) \neq 0$? On intervals $[2n-1,2n] f'(x)=0$, and between we have this bridge that connects two such intervals and I see that derivative is not 0 there but it decreases when $x$ increases since the bridge has to "travel" $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ in vertical and 1 distance in horizontal, so I think $f'(x)$ goes to 0 at infinity.

It is an example from the book counterexamples in analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you, this doesn't seem to work. But if you scale the non-constant intervals in the $x$-direction by a factor of $\alpha$, then you increase $f'(x)$ by a factor of $1/\alpha$. So set $\alpha=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ to have $f'(x)$ not tend to zero; set $\alpha=\frac{1}{n^3}$ to have $f'(x)$ be unbounded. I expect this is what they had in mind.

Comment: So lets say we scale by $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, now the "bridge intervals" are shrinked, the bridge travel $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ in vertical and $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ in horizontal direction so by mean value theorem in every such interval there exist point $c$ such that $f'(c)=-1$, definietly not approach 0 at infinity. Because the "bridge intervals" are shorter now we just lengthen the "constant intervals". Did I get you right?

Comment: @romperextremeabuser: Yes. (But note that you can't shrink the constant intervals too, because the sum of the interval lengths would converge to a finite value, beyond which the function would not be defined.)

Comment: yes, I said that we lenghten the constant intervals by $1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: My original thought was that the constant intervals can stay as they are, but lengthening them works just as well (and makes the explicit formulas easier). I think your method is better.

Answer (score 1):

I used Mathematica to plot the function as you described it:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-1/x^2*Exp[-1/(1 - x)^2]];
g[x_, n_] := 1/n - (1/n - 1/(n + 1))*f[x];
h[x_] := If[Mod[x, 2] >= 1, 1/Ceiling[x/2], g[Mod[x, 2], Floor[x]/2]];
Quiet@Plot[h[x], {x, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> {{1, 20}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: h[x]]

And its derivative:

```
Quiet@Plot[Abs[h'[x]], {x, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
Quiet@Plot[Abs[h'[x]], {x, 100000, 100010}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: h']
[image: h']

Indeed, it does seem like you are right: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f'(x) =0.$$